# Re-ordering a single item from the results of a query

Tags: c#, .net, plsql

I am looking for an elegant solution to an ordering problem I am having.

I have a database query that returns a list of results that is ordered by name.  The results will always contain one item called "Main Item" that always needs to appear first in the list of results.  This item is not flagged by a separate field in the database and so it needs to be identified by name.

For example, if the results are as follows:

```
"A Item"
"B Item"
"Main Item"
"Y Item"
"Z Item"
```

I need the alphabetical sort to remain, but with the exception that "Main Item" appears first:

```
"Main Item"
"A Item"
"B Item"
"Y Item"
"Z Item"
```

The query that returns this data is written in pl/sql and I can either modify the query or do something on the .Net side where I have an IEnumerable object containing a collection of the resulting objects.

Comment: How big is the collection on the client?  Is it large enough or called often enough to prohibit client-side sorting?

Comment: Not large, typically less than 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack your order's:

```
query
  .OrderBy(item => item.Title) // alphabetical
  .OrderByDescending(item => item.Title == "Main Item"); // put Main Item first, bool==true
```

**EDIT**

The list is preordered, only the 2nd `OrderBy` is needed int that case

```
query.OrderByDescending(item => item.Title == "Main Item");
```

Comment: That's a slick answer.  I only need the 2nd orderby since the collection is already sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @zaq ah, i read your post too quickly, I see now you say it is preordered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY 
        CASE 
            WHEN Name = 'Main Item' THEN ' ' 
            ELSE Name 
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I like payo's answer, but since it iterates through the entire collection for a second time instead of a simple element movement logic, I think it's appropriate to post this answer as well:

```
List<MyClass> items = GetItemsFromDB();

int i = items.FindIndex(x => x.Name == "Main Item");

MyClass mainItem = items[i];
items.RemoveAt(i);
items.Insert(0, mainItem);
```

Comment: Meh. `FindIndex` is O(n) just the same. Looks a lot like _premature (micro) optimization_ to me: The list needs to be awful long for any measurable effect, worst case performance is still identical. The code is now become error prone the hard to read.

Comment: @sehe The code remains very visible in my opinion, and there IS an improvement in best case scenario, which should be considered just as much.

Comment: @sehe And you can improve the search algorithm complexity to nLogn, etc. The point of this answer was the single element-movement logic.

Comment: My point is, there is no realistic improvement even in the best case: the list won't be large enough to make that difference: [`Not large, typically less than 10`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391809/re-ordering-a-single-item-from-the-results-of-a-query/10392108#comment13400423_10391809)

Comment: The other problem is that I have an IEnumerable not a list and it does not support RemoveAt or Insert.